# Jquery - How to get the style display attribute "none / block"

Tags: jquery, coding-style, attributes

Is there a way to get the style: display attribute which would have either none or block?

DIV :

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContentAreaPlaceHolder_cellPhone_input_msg_container" class="Error cellphone" style="display: block;">

     <p class="cellphone" style="display: block;">Text</p>

</div>
```

I know that there is a way to find out if the DIV is hidden or not but in my case this div is dynamically injected so it always shows up as visible false thus I cannot use that :

```
$j('.Error .cellphone').is(':hidden')
```

I am able to get the result "display:block" using :

```
$j('div.contextualError.ckgcellphone').attr('style')
```

Is there a way to get just the value "block" or "none" or is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You could try:

```
$j('div.contextualError.ckgcellphone').css('display')
```

Answer (score 84):

If you're using jquery 1.6.2 you only need to code

```
$('#theid').css('display')
```

for example:

```
if($('#theid').css('display') == 'none'){ 
   $('#theid').show('slow'); 
} else { 
   $('#theid').hide('slow'); 
}
```

Answer (score 36):

this is the correct answer

```
$('#theid').css('display') == 'none'
```

You can also use following line to find if it is display block or none

```
$('.deal_details').is(':visible')
```

Comment: Since you're attempting to do an equality check, shouldn't you be using '===' instead of '=='?

Comment: Checking with .css("display") and .is(":visible") are not the same things. If parent element has "display: none", they will give different results. Be careful.

Answer (score 3):

My answer

```
/**
 * Display form to reply comment
 */
function displayReplyForm(commentId) {
    var replyForm = $('#reply-form-' + commentId);
    if (replyForm.css('display') == 'block') { // Current display
        replyForm.css('display', 'none');
    } else { // Hide reply form
        replyForm.css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//animated show/hide

function showHide(id) {
      var hidden= ("none" == $( "#".concat(id) ).css("display"));
      if(hidden){
          $( "#".concat(id) ).show(1000);
      }else{
          $("#".concat(id) ).hide(1000);
      }
  }
```