# Get the count of Divs from their style property in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I am trying to the get the count of `div` which has `style` `display` `block`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
</div>
```

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrapper").each(function(){
        var wrapLength = $('.sub').length;
        $(".sub").each(function(){
            if($(".sub").css("display","none")){
                wrapLength = wrapLength - 1;
            }
        }); 
        alert(wrapLength);
    }); 
});
```

Now I am getting the count as `0` but I should get the count as `2`. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - How to get the style display attribute "none / block"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875403/jquery-how-to-get-the-style-display-attribute-none-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.filter()` method combined with Javascript `style` property for that :

```js
let shownSubs = $('.sub').filter((_,e) => e.style.display == 'block');
console.log(shownSubs.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `$('.sub:hidden').length` to get `display:none` and `$('.sub:visible').length;` element count.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrapper").each(function(){
        var wrapLength = $('.sub:hidden').length;
        console.log(`Hidden count: ${wrapLength}`);
        var visibleLength = $('.sub:visible').length;
        console.log(`Visible count: ${visibleLength}`)
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var count_none = 0;
            $(".sub").each(function() {
                    var style_el = $(this).attr('style');
                    if (style_el == 'display:none') {
                        count_none++;
                    }
                });
                console.log(count_none);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var count=0;
$(".sub").each(function(){
if($(this).css("display")=='block'){
count++;
}
})
alert("total display blocked items :"+count);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:block">text</div>
  <div class="sub" style="display:none">text</div>
</div>
```

hope this solves your query.